# mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target '/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtil s/typemap', needed by 'Random.c'. in Perl for windows 7

Tags: windows, perl, math, random

I used strawberry perl in windows 7. I need to install Math::Random.

using command:

```
1. perl Makefile.PL phrtsd_orig
2. "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
3. "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" test
4. "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" install
```

But the 2nd command give error:

> Skip blib/lib/Math/test1.pl (unchanged)
>   Skip blib/lib/Math/example.pl (unchanged)
>   Skip blib/lib/Math/test2.pl (unchanged)
>   Skip blib/lib/Math/Random.pm (unchanged)
>   Running Mkbootstrap for Math::Random ()
>
> chmod 644 "Random.bs"
>   mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target '/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtil
>   s/typemap', needed by 'Random.c'.  Stop.

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Strawberry Perl, Windows 7 64bit:

```
Math-Random-0.72>perl Makefile.PL phrtsd_orig
dmake
dmake test
dmake install
```

Works fine. Strawberry Perl ships with it's own built tools, use them for building modules.

Comment: dmake gives error:

>CreateProcess failed (2).
dmake:  Error executing '/bin/sh /S /c ""/usr/bin/perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Install
-e 'pm_to_blib(@ARGV, '\''blib/lib/auto'\'', q[], '\''755'\'')' --        Random
.pm blib/lib/Math/Random.pm       example.pl blib/lib/Math/example.pl     test1.
pl blib/lib/Math/test1.pl         test2.pl blib/lib/Math/test2.pl "': No such fi
le or directory
dmake:  Error code -1, while making 'pm_to_blib'

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul the above works perfectly, I can't make this not work. What does `perl -V` show?

Comment: perl -V shows:

Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 22 subversion 0) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=msys, osvers=2.1.4(0.28753), archname=x86_64-msys-thread-multi
    uname='msys_nt-6.1 cab8 2.1.4(0.28753) 2015-06-08 22:11 x86_64 msys '
    config_args='-des -Dusethreads -Doptimize=-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -
pipe -Dprefix=/usr -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl5/core_perl -Dar
chlib=/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl -Dsitelib=/usr/share/perl5/site_perl -Dsitearch=/
usr/lib/perl5/site_perl

Comment: You're really making it difficult to help you with these questions. No MSWin32 platform here, this is MSYS. You're mixing and matching environments and making things difficult for yourself

Comment: I am new in perl. Can you please guide me on it?

Comment: The answer I provided is accurate and working for the environment you claimed you were using. Open a normal Windows command prompt and try it.